# SharePoint - Reference file in item properties

Tags: development

(Disclaimer: This is the first time I deal with SharePoint)

I am trying to add a file in SharePoint and reference it in a property of a list item. The property type is 'Sparqube Lookup Classic' (I had no idea what that was but a quick search led me to this: http://www.sparqube.com/SharePoint-Lookup-Column/).

What ever I try I seem to fail. I have searched on-line, but no relevant results came up (wrong search terms probably?).

Here is my half-functioning code. The item has no file attached in that (`_x03a8__x03b7__x03c6__x03b9__x03`) property when the code finishes.

```
    public void PublishDocToSP()
    {
        var clientContext = GetClient();
        SP.Client.File file;
        var folderName = "DocLib";

        // Upload file - Works OK.
        {
            var fileName = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.pdf";
            var folder = clientContext.Web.Folders.GetByUrl(clientContext.Url + '/' + folderName);

            var info = new FileCreationInformation
            {
                ContentStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read),
                Overwrite = false,
                Url = clientContext.Url + '/' + folderName + '/' + Path.GetFileName(fileName),
            };
            file = folder.Files.Add(info);
            folder.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        // Add item in list and reference file in property. Not working!
        {
            var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(Guid.Parse("{6F15AACD-1132-4BD8-AC7D-36EA1A336D5C}"));

            var itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation()
                                     {
                                         //FolderUrl
                                         //LeafName
                                         //UnderlyingObjectType
                                     };
            var li = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            li["DocmanId"] = 111;
            li["Title"] = "adfadfadfaf";
            li["Email_x0020__x039a__x03b1__x03c4"] = "trehagireue@mailcom"; // Email
            li["_x0391__x0394__x0391_"] = "ΑΗ-ΓΑ...";
            li["_x0391__x03c1__x03b9__x03b8__x03"] = "dfgdfg-sdf";
            li["_x03a8__x03b7__x03c6__x03b9__x03"] = new SP.SPFieldUrlValue(clientContext.Url + '/' + folderName + '/' + "file.pdf"){Description = "Test Desc"};
            li.Update();
            list.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            var insertedId = li.Id;
        }
    }
```

Any idea what I am missing?

**UPDATE:**

Following Vadim Gremyachev's advice I got this:

```
var lv0 = item["_x03a8__x03b7__x03c6__x03b9__x03"] as Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue[];
{Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue[1]}
    [0]: {Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue}
lv0[0]
{Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue}
    base {Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientValueObject}: {Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue}
    LookupId: 532
    LookupValue: "σσσ"
    TypeId: "{f1d34cc0-9b50-4a78-be78-d5facfcccfb7}"
```

Now, I guess I will have to find how to get these data.
I know where the `LookupValue` comes from, but I am not sure about the rest yet...
LookupId seems to be the file ID. I wonder how do I get this from the client. I saw no such property being returned back.

**UPDATE2:**

Finally, I have managed to get the uploaded file ID like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22254339/2173353.
But when I send any of those in the field, I get either an error or nothing as linked files:

```
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint;

string.Format("{0};#{1}", fileID, file.Name);
string.Format("{0};#{1:B}", fileID, listId); //listId is GUID
new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue[] { new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookupValue { LookupId = fileID } };
new SP.SPFieldLookupValueCollection { new SP.SPFieldLookupValue(fileID, file.Name) };
```

I have also tried with no array, just simple FieldLookupValue. That didn't work either. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. It seems that `Sparqube Lookup Classic` uses the file title and cannot work with files that have no title. So, first you have to set the title and then everything works:

```
    public static void PublishDocToSP()
    {
        var clientContext = GetClient();
        SP.Client.File file;
        var folderName = "DocLib";

        // Upload file
        {
            var fileName = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\file.pdf";
            var folder = clientContext.Web.Folders.GetByUrl(clientContext.Url + '/' + folderName);

            var info = new FileCreationInformation
            {
                ContentStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read),
                Overwrite = false,
                Url = clientContext.Url + '/' + folderName + '/' + Path.GetFileName(fileName),
            };
            file = folder.Files.Add(info);

            // !!! I set some value for Title field, because in my case, Title column is Display Column of Sparqube Lookup Classic
            ListItem itemFile = file.ListItemAllFields;
            itemFile["Title"] = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            itemFile.Update();
            clientContext.Load(itemFile);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }

        // Add item in list and reference file in property. Not working!
        {
            var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(Guid.Parse("{F682C057-9715-4F1C-BE1E-D451803FF389}"));
            var itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation()
            {
                //FolderUrl
                //LeafName
                //UnderlyingObjectType
            };
            var li = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            li["Title"] = "adfadfadfaf";

            // Set value for Lookup Classic with single value selection
            li["sqLookupClassic"] = new SP.Client.FieldLookupValue()
            {
                LookupId = file.ListItemAllFields.Id
            };
            // !!! OR
            // li["sqLookupClassic"] = string.Format( "{0};#{1}", file.ListItemAllFields.Id, file.ListItemAllFields["Title"] );

            // !!! If 'Allow multiple values' option is selected for Lookup classic, you should set value in the following way:
            //li["sqLookupClassic"] = string.Format( "{0};#{1};#{2};#{3}", item1.Id, item1["Title"], item2.Id, item2["Title"] );

            li.Update();
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            var insertedId = li.Id;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood the question properly, the actual issue is related with setting value for custom field.  If so, i would suggest the following approach since it is not clear what type of `Sparqube Lookup Classic` column is and therefore what is supported format of its value.

First step would be to determine the format of *custom field value* by getting existing list item, for example:

```
var fieldName = "--The name of Sparqube Lookup Classic column goes here--";
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
ctx.Load(item);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var fieldValue = item[fieldName];  //getting the value of Sparqube Lookup Classic column
```

Once list item is retrieved, I would try to specify `fieldValue` while creating list item:

```
var listItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
listItem[fieldName] = fieldValue;
listItem.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

If this operation will succeed, all you need to do would be to specify the field value in the same format.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH! :) I have updated the question. It seems `TypeId` is constant so I will use that as fixed (probably that's the type of the folder, but that's only a guess from my part...). Do you happen to know a way to get the file ID (which here is the `LookupId`) after I upload it in my folder? Should I try to search it by URL or something to get the newly created ID? I don't see anything returned form the client context... :(

Comment: Aha, so it is of FieldLookup type. In that case you could create the instance of FieldLookupValue and specify LookupId property since it is the only mandatory property. P.S. TypeId property could be ignored

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't seem to work either...:( I don't know why... I have re-updated the question just in case I get any more insights into this.